# Still space between elements (buttons) with "margin: 0"?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/TRVfh/2/

A picture:
[image]

So, right now, there is a little gam in between the two buttons.
and I'd like the buttons to share the middle edge, or at least be touching (if they are touching, changing the CSS so it looks like they are sharing an edge isn't hard)

But Margin left / right doesn't appear to do anything.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two buttons have a space between them because of the return and the indentation you used to format your HTML.

Just float both containers: http://jsfiddle.net/TRVfh/19/

```
.redline_changes, .redline_comments{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px; float: left;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually against floats, as they aren't cross-browser. .. or at least not reliably cross-browser.

Comment: We have CSS Grid Systems (Blueprint, 960, etc.) that rely on floats, what would be the issue of using a float as you as you clear it?

Comment: you mean doing the extra div clear: both; hack? I'm not sure what you mean. I have no formal training in webdesign, so these terms are new to me.

Comment: You can also play around with letter/word spacing, read on at http://lifeathighroad.com/web-development/css-web-development/inline-block-whitespace-workaround/ and see the result at http://jsfiddle.net/TRVfh/27/

Comment: aye, that seems rather hackish to me. unclean. etc. =\

Answer (score 7):

The space is caused by the newline and indentation between the two internal divs. Removing the white space will bring the two closer.

```
<div class="shell" style="width: 950px; ">
        <div class="redline_changes">
            <a href="#">Left Button</a>
        </div><div class="redline_comments">
            <a href="#">Right Button</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove any spaces between DIVs:

```
    <div class="redline_changes">
        <a href="#">Left Button</a>
    </div><div class="redline_comments">
        <a href="#">Right Button</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like extra whitespace in the HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/TRVfh/18/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display:inline` (instead of the current `display:inline-block;`)

http://jsfiddle.net/D269S/

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE.

Comment: I like this approach, but it changes the way the buttons look. I'm playing around with how I can get them back to how they looked before (size-wise)

Answer (score 0):

[I fixed this](http://jsfiddle.net/TRVfh/13/) by adding `margin-left: -5px` to the second button.

Comment: @LEOPiC Apply it to every element with a class and then just set `margin-left: 0px` to the first button

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense just to float them and forget about extra classes?

Comment: @LEOPiC that's what I ended up doing. I hope there is some future CSS trick that is better than float, as float can be weird is some cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's the single space character that's inserted automatically by normalization. Unfortunately, to fix it, you'll need to ruin your code formatting:

```
</div><div class="redline_comments">
            <a href="#">Right Button</a>
        </div>
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/TRVfh/20/)

Comment: isn't there a way to keep my formatting and get rid of the space? or some how tell it to ignore the space?

Answer (score 0):

use `display:flex;`
`flex` stands for flexible layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a spacer with all 0

```
.example-spacer {
  flex: 0 0 0;
}
or
.example-spacer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
or
.example-spacer {
  flex: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to all buttons:

```css
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
display:flex;
float: left;
```